# Javascript Autofill Selection

Tags: javascript, onchange, autofill

I'm searching and searching and can not find anything exactly what I need.

So I need java-script, that will select option from drop down, but not by the option value number, but name. And upon selection the site should display results of my selection. Below is an code from a site that requires me to select option. I want to execute a java-script code that will auto-fill.

I have:

```
<select name="ctl00$ccMain$NZWO" id="ccMain_NZWO" class="Dropdown" onchange="PopulateGrid(this.value)">
            <option value="00">--Select--</option>
            <option value="19">ARGENTINA</option>
            <option value="24">BARCELONA</option>
            <option value="16">CHINA</option>
            <option value="25">JAPAN</option>
            <option value="26">INDONESIA</option>
            <option value="27">INDIA</option>
            <option value="28">USA</option>
            <option value="29">RUSSIA</option>

</select>
```

where I want to select JAPAN and that should make the site run Onchange code of what next after selecting JAPAN.

Thank you

Comment: Look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Hey Sai Tarun Sareddy, let me know if you need any help with my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need this:
onchange="PopulateGrid(this.innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/mc48hsbn/16/

- Add listener (change)
- Run `displayIt()` method
- Alert label

  ```
  document.getElementById("ccMain_NZWO").addEventListener("change", displayIt);

   function displayIt() {
    var selected_value =document.getElementById("ccMain_NZWO").options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    alert(selected_value);
  }


   <select name="ctl00$ccMain$NZWO" id="ccMain_NZWO" class="Dropdown" onchange="PopulateGrid(this.value)">
          <option value="00">--Select--</option>
          <option value="19">ARGENTINA</option>
          <option value="24">BARCELONA</option>
          <option value="16">CHINA</option>
          <option value="25">JAPAN</option>
          <option value="26">INDONESIA</option>
          <option value="27">INDIA</option>
          <option value="28">USA</option>
          <option value="29">RUSSIA</option>

  </select>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a JavaScript code which will select a country and depending on the selection it will populate another drop-down with states of that country .

```
//JavaScript Code
$("#ctl00$ccMain$NZWO").on('change', function(){            
        var country1 = document.getElementById("country").value ;           
        var country_array = country1.split("|") ;           
        var country = country_array[0] ;            
        var name = country_array[1] ;
        var xmlhttp ;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","state.php?action=get_state_names&country="+name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText ;                     
                document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = result ;
            }
        }           
    });

//HTML
<select name="ctl00$ccMain$NZWO" id="ctl00$ccMain$NZWO" class="Dropdown">
        <option value="00">--Select--</option>
        <option value="19|ARGENTINA">ARGENTINA</option>
        <option value="24|BARCELONA">BARCELONA</option>
        <option value="16|CHINA">CHINA</option>
        <option value="25|JAPAN">JAPAN</option>
        <option value="26|INDONESIA">INDONESIA</option>
        <option value="27|INDIA">INDIA</option>
        <option value="28|USA">USA</option>
        <option value="29|RUSSIA">RUSSIA</option>
</select>
```

Actually these country names should come from database , you may need to change your code structure . Anyway the above code will solve your purpose , you may need to change some variable names or display div / dropdown id according to your file . Also you need to set up your state.php file where you need to write the actions which will happen on selecting any country .